# pandas related problem regarding deleting data from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to delete rows from a dataframe which have "No" value in column Auto-Investment. How to do that using pandas dataframe?

```
index = 0
    for x in df3['Auto-Investment']:
        if x == 'No':
            rows = df3.index(index)
            df3.drop(rows, inplace=True)
        index += 1    
    print(df3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
df3 = df3[df3['Auto-Investment'] != 'No']
```

Comment: @Levsha if this work see this link : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by deselecting the ones that are 'no'.

```
df3 = df3[df3['Auto-Investment']!='No']
```

Comment: It is ok my friend :) we all have been there.

Answer (score 1):

Number of solutions:

**1.** `df3 = df3[df3['Auto-Investment']!='No]`

**2.** `df3.drop(df3['Auto-Investment']!='No].index, inplace=True)`

Discussion on which solution is better:
[Pandas drop rows vs filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689823/pandas-drop-rows-vs-filter)

Comment: lol we just did it exactly the same way and time.

Comment: :)))))))))))) Seems that small time difference for such questions is crucial :D

Comment: @Levsha
What should I do when someone answers my question?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Decide if the answer is helpful, and then...
- Vote on it
- Accept it